# Convert String to Clickable Link

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am creating a webpage that displays user history. Written in Java, I have pojo that contains properties that my jsf retrieves via bean injection. The problem: one of the values is a url. Currently, the String is a long url but isn't clickable. Also to note, these values (Strings) are in an ArrayList. How can I assign a String value that contains a url and output a clickable url?

userHistoryDetails.completeData bean may look like this (sudo):

```
[{status=complete,userid=123,reportUrl=http://www.reporturl.com}]
```

example of table created in my jsf file. Where  `#{cRow[cColModel.value]}` creates a row in the table with its respective header value.

```
<ace:dataTable id="completedTable"
    value="#{userHistoryDetails.completeData}" var="cRow"
    paginator="true" rows="50" paginatorPosition="both"
    emptyMessage="NO RECORDS TO DISPLAY">
    <c:forEach items="#{userHistoryDetails.userHistoryHeaders}"
        var="cColModel">
        <ace:column headerText="#{cColModel.headerText}">
                #{cRow[cColModel.value]}
        </ace:column>
                </c:forEach>
</ace:dataTable>
```

Please let me know if this does not make sense. It is kind of hard to explain. Thanks in advance!

EDIT I have tried changing String to:

```
    [{status=complete,userid=123,reportUrl=<a href="http://www.reporturl.com">View report</a>}]
```

but still no luck. I feel like I am on the right track, just missing something.

[image]

Comment: Use the <a> tag

Comment: @BrunoCL tried your suggestion and no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: <a href=your link string here>your text here</a>

Comment: Use a URL in your model and `h:outputLink` in your `ace:column` to create the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I assign a String value that contains a url and output a clickable url?

Two ways:

```xml
<a href="#{bean.url}">#{bean.url}</a>
```

```xml
<h:outputLink value="#{bean.url}">#{bean.url}</h:outputLink>
```

> userHistoryDetails.completeData bean may look like this (sudo):
>
> ```
> [{status=complete,userid=123,reportUrl=http://www.reporturl.com}]
> ```
>
> example of table created in my jsf file. Where `#{cRow[cColModel.value]}` creates a row in the table with its respective header value.

So .. If `#{cColModel.value}` equals to `reportUrl` you want to generate a link? That'll have to look something like this:

```xml
<ui:fragment rendered="#{cColModel.value eq 'reportUrl'}">
    <a href="#{cRow[cColModel.value]}">#{cRow[cColModel.value]}</a>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{cColModel.value ne 'reportUrl'}">
    #{cRow[cColModel.value]}
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :). Seperate issue, I am able to create a clickable link but it redirects to: about:blank#blocked. Have you ever seen this before?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22about%3Ablank%23blocked%22

Comment: I found the issue but wanted to thank you again. The suggestion worked perfectly.